# Embedded Video(& Youtube) on AskUbuntu Questions & Answers?

Tags: discussion

How is it possible to **embed a video** when we submit a new question or answer? Till now, this feature is only applied for images. Any ideas on how to solve this or is this feature currently in progress and will be implemented soon?

Comment: nice idea, come lets give a try.

Comment: @Naresh S Nash I meant is it any way to embed video inside questions? As for myself, I don't have the idea at the moment. haha

Comment: @Gautam Vashisht Thanks buddy! =D

Comment: all those negative votes!?

Comment: @MinaMichael From what I have seen on this site, people mostly frown upon posting links to videos. It is much much faster to read than it is to sit through a 10 or even 5 minute video. Additionally, you can't copy and paste or search the code used in the video and so you have to type everything out and this makes it near impossible to easily execute or even audit the content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an animated sequence was needed to show a procedure that answers the question we can convert any video to an animated GIF sequence. This can then be embedded in a question or an answer.

See [How to create animated GIF images of a screencast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast)

Comment: I will have a reading first from the previous questions which are duplicated by this questions before proceed with my opinion. nice to have this kind of enthusiastic discussion.

Comment: After a few days, without reviewing & observing, I prefer to use your shared suggestion(the link), at least for this time being until there is future idea on how to improve. thanks a lot for(to all buddies) your superb efforts on assisting each of us for a better environment in askubuntu.